# Gmp mpf_pow_ui function

Tags: c, precision, gmp

I am using gmp's mpf_t to try and get very high precision.

My range of precision ranges from negative trillions to positive trillions, as well as 1 over these numbers.  However mpf doesn't support a power function that allows negative exponents, is there a way to get around this if I want to raise my value to 10^-30?

http://gmplib.org/manual/Float-Arithmetic.html#Float-Arithmetic

my gdp output when I try to use mpf_pow_ui, when my exp is negative:

```
(gdb) p exp_multiplier
$9 = {{_mp_prec = 2, _mp_size = 3, _mp_exp = 957480584338323631, _mp_d = 0x605070}}
```

This eventually will cause a segfault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, apply math:

```
10^-30 = 1 / 10^30
```

Just raise it to the positive power and take the reciprocal.

There's a division function `mpf_ui_div()` that takes an integer numerator for that.

Comment: Divide is a costly function to pay for, and a reciprocal function may be just as bad, do you know if mpf natively supports a power function for signed integers?

Comment: The fastest way to to raise to a negative power ***is*** to take the reciprocal. The division is unavoidable. Integer powering is implemented using the [binary squaring method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) - which only takes a positive exponent.

Comment: I was hoping that they would do shifts.  But if that is the only way, I guess I am stuck with it.  Thank you.

Comment: They do use shifts in the division code--not sure if it's quite what you mean, though: http://fossies.org/dox/gmp-5.0.4/ui__div_8c_source.html  and  http://fossies.org/dox/gmp-5.0.4/mpn_2generic_2tdiv__qr_8c_source.html

Comment: Shifts can be used for division. But in general, not for negative powers.